# how to setup cocos2d-x on windows 7..need a n00bs guide !!?

Tags: android, windows, cocos2d-x

well i am on windows 7 ,64 bit,having the ADT bundle for windows..
i am a bit confused with all the tutorials(a) cocos2d-x setup for android on windows 7,also they are too old..after that the cocos2d-x has been updated and i dont want to try and experiment with my current perfect environment set for android...though i have downloaded the CDT plugin and nothing else..

it will be good if anyone helps to configure cocos2d-x for windows 7...

(a)
http://www.raywenderlich.com/11283/cocos2d-x-for-ios-and-android-getting-started
http://gameit.ro/2012/01/creating-an-iphone-and-android-cocos2d-x-hybrid-project-updated/

Answer (score 1):

http://www.cocos2d-x.org/projects/cocos2d-x/wiki/Chapter_1_-_How_to_Create_a_New_cocos2d-x_project_on_multi-platforms#4-Start-with-Android

This totally works on windows 7 but you will need two things:

1. You will need to have administrator privileges else it creates many files which the program itself cant access and things turn out pretty tough.
2. You will have to set a system environment variable for "NDK_ROOT" in your computer. 
   Here is an example of how to do so - http://www.windows7hacker.com/index.php/2010/05/how-to-addedit-environment-variables-in-windows-7/

This worked for me after one week of pain and efforts. I hope this works for you in the first instance.
Good Luck.. :)

Comment: Hi, I'm want to run hello world program in Cocos 2dx in Android in windows7, is that possible share some links that you used while learning cocos2dx in android and development setup in win7. I'm biting my nail from last 1 week!