# How to integrate cocos2d-x/plugin-x IAP in android

Tags: android, plugins, cocos2d-x, in-app-billing

I want to use in app billing in my android app, for doing this i tried to work with cocos2d-x/plugin-x, but i didn't succeed to integrate it.

I followed this [wiki](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/wiki/Plugin-X_Integration_Guide_for_Android) , and i have this message:

```
Android NDK: /Users/yagoub/XXXX/XXXX/proj.android/../cocos2d/cocos/ui/Android.mk: Cannot find module with tag 'protocols/android' in import path    
Android NDK: Are you sure your NDK_MODULE_PATH variable is properly defined ?    
Android NDK: The following directories were searched:    
Android NDK:         
make: Entering directory `/Users/yagoub/XXXXXX/XXXXXXXX/proj.android'
jni/Android.mk:47: *** Android NDK: Aborting.    .  Stop.
make: Leaving directory `/Users/yagoub/XXXXXX/XXXXXXXXXX/proj.android'
Error running command, return code: 2
```

Could you please explain to me the steps for doing that correctly?

Thank you for your time and consideration.

Comment: You need to add the path of **cocos2d-x/plugin-x** in the NDK_MODULE_PATH check out this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16163743/cannot-find-module-with-tag-cocosdenshion-android-in-import-path-error-in-co).

Comment: Once, when I needed to make decision, I selected Soomla solution (https://github.com/soomla/cocos2dx-store) for IAP in my cocos2d-x games. You can have a look as well.